# Interval arithmetic and implicit function inside test

Tags: implicit

I has implicit function and square region. I need to check this region for presence of part of curve, with *interval arithmetic* only.

My attempt:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
f[a_Interval, b_Interval] := Sin[a + b] - Cos[a*b] + 1;
s = 1.1;(*Square size*)
cx = -3.9; (*Square center x*)
cy = -1.2; (*Square center y*)

x = Interval[{cx - s/2, cx + s/2}];
y = Interval[{cy - s/2, cy + s/2}];

IntervalMemberQ[f[x, y], 0]
```

Does this code are correctly solve the problem?

**Update:**
I need to get a `false` if the curve is guaranteed not in the specified square(include inner area). But `true` value cannot guaranteed the opposite

Comment: BTW, AroundReplace[
 Sin[a + b] - Cos[a*b] + 1, {a -> Around[-3.9, 0.55], 
  b -> Around[-1.2, 0.55]}] performs a worser result Around[2,2.5].

Comment: The implicit curve is given by `f[a,b]==0`? And you want to determine whether `f[square1,square2]` hits zero?

Comment: The above code giving `False` is sufficient but not necessary condition for the square in question to contain no zero. Changing `s` to 2.0, for example, will give a result of `True` when in fact this larger square still contains no zero.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I need to get a `false` if the curve is guaranteed not in the specified square(include inner area). But `true` value cannot guaranteed the opposite.

Comment: A `False` is a guarantee of no intersection. So if that is all you require, the code is fine for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely correctly in view of

```
NMinimize[{Sin[a + b] - Cos[a*b] + 1, a >= -3.9 - 0.55&& a <= -3.9 + 0.55 && b >= -1.2 - 0.55 &&   
 b <= -1.2 + 0.55}, {a, b}]
```

> {0.38735,{a->-4.45,b->-1.4593}}

Answer (score 1):

The function does not achieve a zero within the square (as is supported by[`NMinimize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html).

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[Abs[x + 3.9] < 0.55 &&Abs[y + 1.2] < 0.55, {{x, -5, 0}, {y, -2, 0}}];
Show[ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0, {x, -5, 0}, {y, -5, 0}],RegionPlot[reg]]
```

[image]

Or it can be seen by plotting region and plane z=0:

```
{m, w} = NMinimize[f[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] reg];
pnt = {Sequence[x, y], m} /. w;
Show[Plot3D[{f[x, y], 0}, {x, y} \[Element] reg, Mesh -> None], 
 Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{-3.9, -1.2, f[-3.9, -1.2]}],
    Green, Point[pnt]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I updated my question, please take a look